# Why does custard go runny if left exposed in the fridge, what is the chemical reaction?

Tags: refrigerator, custard

If I leave opened custard in a carton with just the spout open the custard remains thick the next day, but spread out on a plate its like water the following day.

Is it water inside the environment?

UPDATE: 7 days later : the custard from the same carton opened is still thick!

Comment: What exactly is custard in a carton? Can you post a picture? Or at least identify what country you're in? Because in my experience, a spout on a container of custard will have exactly zero utility, so I can't imagine what manner of beast you're talking about.

Comment: Could you also list ingredients. (I’m thinking it absorbed water from the air)

Comment: Apologies, I should have been more specific. The carton is this one, from a UK supermarket:

https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/custard/sainsburys-ready-to-eat-custard-500g

Snipping off the end, the spout, just leaves a small orifice. While custard left exposed, poured over a larger flatter surface, like a plate, leaves it more like water the following day, while the packing version remains thick.

Comment: Ingredients: Reconstituted Skimmed Milk (from Cows' Milk); Sugar; Modified Maize Starch; Vegetable Oil (contains: Palm Oil, Coconut Oil); Flavouring; Stabiliser: Sodium Triphosphate; Colours: Beta-carotene; Paprika Extract.

Comment: photo: https://i.postimg.cc/sgJxmqZR/custard.png